# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users' Rails 5 tutorial

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Running tests on Rails on the built Sample App (Michael Hartl Rails 5), When running tests I get the above error, which suggests it can't find the table 'users', it's available in my db migrate folder and also listed in the development.sqlite3 file, So not sure what the issue is

Tried the recommended fixes running rake db:test:prepare, rails db:migrate:reset testing to see if User.new(name: 'foo') creates a user neither have fixed the problem and the latter creates fine in the console so can't understand why it can't find the table

_create_users.rb

```
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

tests to run errors run when attempting 'rails test:mailers' and more when using 'rails test'

[db:migrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYuwf.png)
[SQLite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH1NY.png)

Comment: was working before I generated the below: `'rails generate migration add_reset_to_users reset_digest:stringreset_sent_at:datetime'` this created an issue, I believe because of the  missed space so I ran this: `'rails generate migration add_reset_to_users reset_digest:string reset_sent_at:datetime'` & then `'rails generate migration add_reset_sent_at_to_users reset_sent_at:datetime'` which fixed the previous issue, but now tests don't work

Comment: What do you mean with "don't work", can you elaborate your question?

Comment: When the tests are run using `rails test:mailers` it gives the error as above and the suggested fixes from other posts haven't rectified the problem:

Comment: ERROR["test_account_activation", UserMailerTest, 0.21548007300043537]
 test_account_activation#UserMailerTest (0.22s)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to remember that each environment in Rails has its own database. Just because your application is working when you're doing development (`RAILS_ENV=development`), it doesn't mean the database is there when running tests (`RAILS_ENV=test`).

You may simply need to prepare your test database (create it and migrate it):

```
# Drop any test DB you already have
bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test

# Create a clean fresh one
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test

# Import the Schema from your schema.rb, rather than run all migrations
bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
```

If you do the above and then run your tests, they should work as expected.

Comment: Hi I've tried the above, still coming up with the same error's. Now tested on development website and appears the users table is no longer there either, can't see how it would have been deleted

Comment: Is the users table in your `schema.rb`? Perhaps you need to `rake db:migrate` in your development environment to get it back into your `schema.rb` properly, and then my commands above might work?

Comment: I found the issue defined in the schema, related to the above typo `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20190804192901) do

# Could not dump table "users" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'stringreset_sent_at' for column 'reset_digest'` I missed the space earlier, but now not sure how I can rectify this, maybe I can rollback the database?

Comment: If you don't have production data to worry about, you can simply fix the migration and then `rake db:drop`, `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Thanks, worked after I deleted the original migrate file I made with typo - fixed and I now understand migrations more, cheers