# ActiveRecord will create database upon migrations but can't find it when I try to save something or produce a schema

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord, sinatra-activerecord

I'm trying to save a User but ActiveRecord can't find my table.  Also 'rake db:schema:dump' does not produce a schema.rb file, I have done my create table migrations and the default 'development.sqlite' database has been created when I do so.  Afterwards I enter:

```
pry(main)> User.create({username: "test", email: "foo@bar.com", password_digest: "foobar"})
```

and see :

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
> from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:346:in `table_structure'

upon sticking a 'binding.pry' on line 346 in sqlite3_adapter.rb I try to find the value of both "table_name" and "@config" and I see that both of these appear to be set up correctly:

```
pry(#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter>)> table_name
```

> => "users"

```
[2] pry(#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter>)> @config
```

> => {:adapter=>"sqlite3", :database=>"db/development.sqlite"}

This appears to be correct to me unless I am missing something.  I wrote the migration as:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
    end
  end
end
```

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349953/activerecordstatementinvalid-could-not-find-table-users-rails-5-tutorial) and have been googling.  Looking for a clue as to what might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to "run" the migration:

```
rails db:migrate
```

Comment: unfortunately I have done this, and also running 'rake db:rollback' is not fixing the issue either.

Comment: what is the output of the db:migrate task?